# How to get the value of a CSS definition in JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx

Is it possible to just get the value of a CSS-definition in JavaFX?

For example in CSS:

```
.root {
    defined-violet: rgb(110,50,160);    
}
```

And in JavaFX:

```
String cssValue = getValueOf("defined-violet");
System.out.println(cssValue); //this should print rgb(110,50,160)

private String getValueOf(String s) {
  //do something to get the value
  return value;
}
```

I would appreciate any hint to the right answer.

Comment: There's (currently) no API for this. Can you explain why you need it? Maybe there's a different solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @James_D it's because I have a program where some values come from CSS and others are directly defined in the javacode. Now I just want all the definitions to be in a single CSS-file, so that they aren't split.

Answer (score -2):

well you can save your self the pain of right the recipe for this and do this

```
private String getValueOf(String s){
     Rectangle rect = new Retangle(10,10);
     rect.setStyle(s);
     return rect.getFill().toString;
}
```